# How to render a MP4 movie from HTML animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, web

Basically I'm looking for somehow to render a MP4 movie from some animation in HTML Canvas or SVG animated.

I don't need to have some preview of it. I'm just thinking that I could give some texts and images and the code would render these into a video with this content animated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: *You mean you want us to code an actual mp4 encoder for you?!* That's too big an ask for a Stackoverflow question. But you're in luck! You could use [Whammy](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy) by antimatter15 to encode Canvas content to a .WebM video. Then you can cross-encode the .webm into .mp4 with one of the many online converters. If you just want to screen grab an animating canvas into a video file on your development computer then you can video capture with [SnagIt](https://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html).

Comment: @markE it's now part of the specs :) (except the mp4 format since it is a proprietary format)

Comment: @Kaiido. `canvas.captureStream` == Cool! Thanks for mentioning it (it was new to me). :-)

Comment: @markE My bad, I didn't meant that. Just wanted to know whether was possible and whether already exist some solution for it. Whammy is cool, but I wished I could generate something with more quality.

Answer (score -2):

I don't entirely understand your question but if you're trying to simply include something like an SVG link you can do this:

```
<img src="kiwi.svg" alt="Kiwi standing on oval">
```

You should also check out Spritely: http://spritely.net/ May help you.

Comment: hehe Nope. How can I say that in other words? Imagine you wrote a code where a circle goes from left to right. What I need is get this event and render into a MP4 movie.

Comment: I updated my answer a bit. Sadly its just not quiet that simple. If you're trying to make web animations you might want to check out the link above.